# Lookup via Annotation in Weblogic

Tags: java, annotations, ejb-3.0, weblogic, weblogic11g

I am using EJB3.0, Weblogic 11g

I am trying to do simple lookup from servlet to Statelessbean and run there a method. both under the same EAR.
I managed to do it with Jboss. but I know that in Weblogic it's little bit diffrent so I channged my code and this is what I am doing and still no success:

The interface I have declared:

```
 @Local
 public interface OperatorBlockBeanLocal
 {
    public void testme();

 }
```

This is the class which implements the Interface:

```
@Stateless
@Local{ OperatorBlockBeanLocal.class })


@JNDIName(value = "OperatorBlockBean")


 public class OperatorBlockBean implements OperatorBlockBeanLocal
 {
    public void testme()
 {
    System.out.println("OperatorBlockBean");
 }
 }
```

And this is the servlet which trying to lookup the bean I decalred before:

```
try
    {
        context = new InitialContext();

        operatorBlockBean = (OperatorBlockBeanLocal) context
                .lookup("java:comp/env/OperatorBlockBean");
        operatorBlockBean.testme();
    } catch (NamingException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Ofcourse that I get NamingException. anyone has any idea?

thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
@Stateless(mappedName="OperatorBlockBean")
@Local{ OperatorBlockBeanLocal.class }
public class OperatorBlockBean implements OperatorBlockBeanLocal
```

You can also use EJB injection in your servlet and not do a lookup.  Here's how:

```
@EJB OperatorBlockBeanLocal operatorBlockBean;
```

The EJB will injected so you don't have to do a lookup.

Comment: Is my lookup address right? coz it doesnt work with loop up. this is the errpr: While trying to look up comp/env/OperatorBlockBean in /app/webapp/SBNWeb/10178340.; remaining name 'comp/env/OperatorBlockBean'

Comment: Now I must do lookup coz I am outside of my container. any idea how to do that?